# ArgumentCountError Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I am trying to target an edit on the standardId property of the DB. For now I am manually typing the ID value into the Input field for standard ID but ideally I will have the property as not visible eventually.

When attempting to edit existing properties in DB I receive the following error:

Type: Argument Count Error

Message: Too few arguments to function Standards::edit(), 0 passed in D:\xamp\htdocs\myisogo\system\core\CodeIgniter.php on line 532 and exactly 1 expected

Filename: D:\xamp\htdocs\myisogo\application\controllers\Standards.php

Line Number: 39

Model:

```
public function edit_standard()
{
    $this->load->helper('url');

    $data = array(
        'standardid' => $this->input->post('standardId'),
        'standardcode' => $this->input->post('standardCode'),
        'standardname' => $this->input->post('standardName')
    );

    return $this->db->insert('isostandard', $data);
}
```

Controller:

```
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $data['standard'] = $this->standard_model->get_standard_byId($standard_id);

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('standardId', 'standardid', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('standardCode', 'standardcode', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('standardName', 'standardname', 'required');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE)
    {
        $this->load->view('templates/header');
        $this->load->view('templates/navbar');
        $this->load->view('standards/edit', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }
    else
    {
        $this->standard_model->edit_standard();
        $this->load->view('standards/success');
    }
```

View:

```
<?php echo form_open('standards/edit'); ?>

<h1>Amend Existing standard </h1>
<h2><?php echo $standard['standardId']; ?></h2>

<label for = "title"> Standard ID </label>
<input type="input" name = "standardId"/><br />

<label for="title">Standard Code</label>
<input type="input" name="standardCode" /><br />

<label for="text">Standard Title</label>
<textarea name="standardName"></textarea><br />

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Create new standard" />

</form>
```

Comment: `$standard_id``is the parameter of your edit method?

Comment: Yeah that's correct

Comment: See my answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that your method from Standards::edit is:

```
public function edit($standard_id)
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $data['standard'] = $this->standard_model->get_standard_byId($standard_id);

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('standardId', 'standardid', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('standardCode', 'standardcode', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('standardName', 'standardname', 'required');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE)
    {
        $this->load->view('templates/header');
        $this->load->view('templates/navbar');
        $this->load->view('standards/edit', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }
    else
    {
        $this->standard_model->edit_standard();
        $this->load->view('standards/success');
    }
}
```

In this case $standard_id is always required. Right?

But the problem is your form_open. You are passing an URL without the id.

```
<?php echo form_open('standards/edit'); ?>
```

With this, when you submit the form, you'll submit to `//localhost/standards/edit`, but COdeIgniter only accepts `//localhost/standards/edit/<some_id_here>`.

You have two choices

1. Do not pass url to form_open, since you are not posting to other endpoint.
   `<?php echo form_open(); ?>`
2. Edit your form_open and concat the id
   `<?php echo form_open("standards/edit/{$standard['standardId']}"); ?>`

**I stick with the first one.**

If you want to make a parameter optional you need to assign the default value `public function edit($standard_id=null)`

Comment: Thank you so much. It finally clicked. Essentially I was not passing the required argument into the method and that was the reasons for the error. Marked as best answer.